# why do some sites have a 'img.' site?

Tags: subdomain

an example of what i am asking, the website

www.discogs.com

has all of its image paths (the ones iv looked at) leading to here:

www.**img**.discogs.com

and i have seen other sites similar - usually ones that store lots of images (which i am intending to do).

do they just simply purchase a new domain with the '**img.**' within it, or is it an image hosting specialised site or..?

if it is simply purchasing an additional site to store the images, is there any information etc on how to go about setting this up i.e. is a login system required on the storage site, or security considerations etc... can image uploading be done through the 'main' site or would it need to be done through the '**img.**' site.

i have tried to google, but im pretty poor at naming things correctly and so havn't found any answers as yet.

if anybody could shed some light on this i would be very much grateful! thanks in advance...

why do some sites have a 'img.' site?

*wasn't sure what tag to put for this one, if incorrect please let me know*

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not server/site set up. That being said, serving static images is highly bandwidth intensive, but not very cpu intensive, so it makes sense (sometimes) to split that off onto its own dedicated server(s).

Comment: If it's img.[anotherdomain.com] they wouldn't be purchasing it, it's just a subdomain of their existing domain.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/46830/how-do-cdn-content-delivery-networks-server-work?rq=1

Comment: thank you very much for the linked resources, i will look further into subdomains, i have noticed an option for them on my current hosting.

Answer (score 0):

2 reasons.

1) caching policies are usually per subdomain which allows more aggressive caching on IMG. while using normal caching for the main website as it may be dynamic.

2) it may be a different server, a high storage one. The main website is running the main apps hogging all the performance and the image subdomain allows for a separate, high speed delivery.